# Regex to identify catgory pages but exclude products

Tags: regex, google-analytics

I want to just see data for URLs which contain collection + category in google analytics so URLs which contain /collections/category example: https://baileynelson.com.au/collections/glasses

However i don't want to see data for products example: https://baileynelson.com.au/collections/glasses/products/adler

The regex i created is: ^/collections/(.*?)$ but it seems to be including product URLs.

Any ideas on how to create regex just so collection pages like https://baileynelson.com.au/collections/glasses, https://baileynelson.com.au/collections/sunglasses - but then product URLs are excluded?

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Try using this regex [here](https://regexr.com/4vqbr).

`https:\/\/baileynelson\.com\.au\/collections\/[\w]+`

The first part: `htttps:\/\/baileynelson\.com\.au\/collections\/` This matches the domain and the path collections. The `/`s and `.`s are escaped.

Second part: `[\w]+` This matches any words (abcde...z), and the `+` makes it so that is matches any amount.

Comment: Hey thanks for that, i entered the regex into google analytics: https://share.getcloudapp.com/z8uXOZWk i'm getting collections which is good but products also seem to be appear, any advice on how to exclude those?